# Sitelink search box does not appear on Google after adding JSON-LD SearchAction to my site yesterday

Tags: seo, structured-data, json-ld, google-sitelinks-searchbox

I added the JSON-LD code to my site but search bar did not appear. What is the reason for this? am i doing something wrong?

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/",
        "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "https://www.example.com/search?term={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Your site currently has sitelinks in Google search when you search for your brand or domain?

Comment: yes, there are sitelinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google only displays the sitelinks search box for your domain if they feel like it, even if your markup is well-formed.

[From Google's guidelines for searchbox structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox):

> **Important:** Google doesn't guarantee that a sitelinks search box will be shown in search results. Additionally, using the sitelinks search box markup doesn't make it more likely that a sitelinks search box will be shown. For a list of common reasons why Google may not show structured data in search results, review the [General Structured Data Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies).

If you've implemented the markup, the only thing left to do is wait and hope, and maybe improve your site's SEO in a very general sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the code yesterday, you probably just need to wait.   It takes Google at on average two weeks to discover and process any changes you make to your site and make changes to the search results.

For this to happen:

1. Googlebot need to crawl the page.   Googlebot crawls most pages every couple weeks.  It crawls very popular pages several times a day, but it crawls pages with no remaining links to them every few months.    The home page of your site where you implemented this code is likely to be the page on your site that is crawled most often.  Most sites get their home page crawled at least weekly.
2. Google needs to process the changes.   This can also take a week.